# Obtaining WW2 records from the Dienststelle?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2

My grandfather worked for the German Post office May 1940 to end of war. I have a copy of a letter that my grandfather received in August 1944 while he was living there asking/ordering him to relocate to Ulm, Germany by September 1944. This copy I have indicates when he started, group number 8 ortsklasse. If I was to get in touch with the Dienststelle and send a scanned copy of both sides, would it help to locate the records faster?

Unfortunately, my last name is different from his, but I do have a long form copy of my birth certificate and marriage certificate of my parents. My grandfather's name appears on the marriage certificate so I can prove a connection. Also, would these records indicate previous military information or citizenship?

Comment: For the full military record you just need name, birth date and maybe place of origin. They might ask for details on your relationship, this is where you certificates will help. If your grandfather worked for for the Reichspost only, I assume the Deutsche Dienststelle has no records on him however.

Comment: I am not quite sure of all the details. I do have a couple of photos of him in a military uniform. Not sure if it is from the Wehrmacht. Also, the letter he received while in Lublin makes reference to Der Prasident der Reichpostdirektion III B 3  8630-OU on one side.  On the other in a paragraph near the bottom it makes reference to Gruppe VIII Ortsklasse and in brackets at the bottom of the paragraph Dienstsiegel